# Jack not recognizing MIDI device

Tags: linux, alsa, jack

Jack does not recognize my MIDI keyboard, whereas ALSA does. 
Here are the logs :

```
pi@raspberrypi / $ jack_lsp 
system:playback_1 
system:playback_2
LinuxSampler:midi_in_0 
LinuxSampler:0 
LinuxSampler:1
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi / $ amidi -l 
Dir Device    Name 
IO  hw:1,0,0  nanoKEY2 MIDI 1
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi / $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [nanoKEY2       ]: USB-Audio - nanoKEY2
                      KORG INC. nanoKEY2 at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2, full speed
```

What could be the problem ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Which Jack implementation are you using? How have you configured it?

Comment: I'm using Jack2. I've ran it with "jackd -P84 -t2000 -d alsa -dhw:0 -p512 -n2 -r44100 -s -P -Xseq  &"

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 distinct midi systems:

The alsa kernel subsytem takes care of physical devices, that can be connected to apps that use the alsa interface.

The Jack midi system is more recent, and is more suited to transmit midi messages between jack apps.

There are several utilities to connect both systems: `a2j` can replicate dynamically all alsa midi ports in jack; `a2jmidi_bridge` let you define static ports.